# Nodejs/typescript pass multipe parametes validations

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I've the following function which need to get the following parameters

```
        try {
         await setData(generator.eventType, generator.eventVersion, generator.uri, ms.data.data.result.name, generator.app)

        } catch (error) {
            logger.error("error occured : ", error)
            return error
        }
    }
```

Now in case that one of the properties are not having data like "undefiend" the function `setData` will not work.

To handle it in advance I need to create **ugly if statement for each property** (that is passed to the function)  to check if the value is supplied otherwise throw error,

My question is if there is a **cleaner** way to handle validation in typescript/nodejs ?

Comment: i would recommend variation of  [Null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern)

Comment: @robert - thanks, could you provide some example in typescript

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at https://github.com/scopsy/typescript-param-validator

```
import { Validator, Validate } from 'typescript-param-validator';
import { IsDate, IsNotEmpty, MaxDate, IsEmail, Length } from 'class-validators';

class DataDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsEmail()
  email: string;
  
  @Length(10, 200)
  @IsNotEmpty()
  description: string;
  
  @IsDate()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @MaxDate(new Date())
  birthDate: Date;
}

class TestClass {
  @Validate()
  methodName(@Validator() data: DataDto) {
    
  }

  @Validate()
  serverControllerEndpoint(@Validator(DataDto, 'body') req: Request) {
    
  }
}
```